# Why does Nil :: Nil give back List(List())?

Tags: scala

When I do 4 :: Nil , I get List(4) . I could understand it because when a empty list is prepended with 4 it gives single element list . But when I do Nil :: Nil , I get List with single Empty List i.e List(List()) , why does it behave this way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, `Nil` represents an empty list or `List()`. The `::` operator takes one element and adds it to the beginning of the list. It does not concatenate two lists. For eg., `1::List(2,3,4)` returns `List(1,2,3,4)`.

So when you do `4::Nil` or `4::List()` it returns `List(4)`. Similarly `Nil::Nil` or `List()::List()` takes the empty list and adds it to the beginning of the other empty list. So you get `List(List())`.

But if you use the concatenation operator `:::` ie., `Nil:::Nil`, it concatenates the two empty lists and returns another empty list `List()`.

Answer (score 2):

The right-hand `Nil` is the empty list, as before, but the type of that list is set by the element being prepended to it. In this case, this is the left-hand `Nil`, which is thus treated as a new element being prepended to the (right-hand) list. Since the type of `Nil` is `List[_]` (for some - here undetermined - type `_`), the type of the list represented by the right-hand `Nil` will be `List[List[_]]` - a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to understand this would be using how this works:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4) match {
    case firstElem :: tailOfList => println(tailOfList) // List(2, 3, 4)
    case _ => // do something else
}
```